# Expect Coin Value Probelm ( a variant of coin change problem)

Tags: probability

You have a wallet with four kinds of coins with the value of \$1, \$5, \$10, and \$25. Every kind of coin is unlimited. Every time you take money from the wallet, you have an equal chance of getting one of these coins, i.e., \$1, \$5, \$10, or \$25.

Now you need to buy something that costs $x$ dollar, and you keep taking coins out of your wallet until you have enough money to buy. When $x$=30, what is the expected value of money left in your hand after your purchase?

i.e., if you take out a \$25 the first time, you have to take more coins since the price is \$30. And suppose you get a \$10 in the second time, you can stop. You pay \$30 and you have \$5 left in your hand.

How about when $x$=300, $x$=3000000?

I have a navie simulation result: \$7,75 for $x$=30, \$8.67 for $x$=300, and \$7.5 for $x$=3000000. While the simulation results is not very precise.

Does anyone know the mathmatical solution?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You should edit the question to include your simulation results.  Information in a comment is more likely to be overlooked.

Comment: @awkward thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat the sequence of the amounts of money you have at any time as a homogeneous discrete-time [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) with states $\ 0,1,\dots,x+24\ $ and transition matrix $\ P=\big(p_{ij}\big)\ $ with entries
\begin{align}
p_{ij}=\cases{\frac{1}{4}&if $\ 0\le i\le x-1\ $ and $\ j-i\in\{1,5,10,25\}\ $,\\
1&if $\ x\le j=i\le x+24\ $,\\
0&otherwise .
}
\end{align}
If $\ j\ge x\ $, then $\ j\ $ is an *absorbing* state. Once you arrive in such a state you have reached or overshot your target, and you will thereafter remain in it.  After spending $\ x\ $ on the object you need to buy you will then have $\ j-x\ $ left.

Since you start off with $\ \$0\ $, your initial probability distribution over the states of the chain is
$$
\pi_0=\pmatrix{1&0&0&\dots&0}\ .
$$
After $\ s\ $ steps, the probability distribution over the states of the chain will be
$$
\pi_s=\pi_0P^s\ .
$$
When $\ s=x\ $ you must have accumulated at least $\ x\ $ dollars, and must therefore have reached one of the absorbing states.  This is reflected mathematically in the fact that, for all $\ s\ge x\ $,
$$
P^s=\pmatrix{0_{x\times x}&0_{x\times25}\\
0_{25\times x}&I_{25\times25}}\ ,
$$
and so
$$
\pi_s=\pi_x\ .
$$
for all such $\ s\ $. Therefore, if
$$
\omega=\pi_0P^x\ ,
$$
then the probability that you will have change of $\ d\ $ dollars left after buying the object you need is $\ \omega_{x+d}\ $, and so the average amount of your change will be
$$
\sum_{d=1}^{24}d\omega_{x+d}\ .
$$
The size of the matrix $\ P\ $ is $\ (x+25)\times(x+25)\ $.  This makes the calculation of the matrix $\ P^x\ $ impractical for values of $\ x\ $ as large as $3,000,000$. However, because the matrix $\ P\ $ is very sparse—it has at most four non-zero values in any column  —, it's quite feasible to compute the values of $\ \pi_1,\pi_2,\dots,\pi_x\ $ successively by using the recursion $\ \pi_{s+1}=\pi_sP\ $.
Here's a [Magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(computer_algebra_system)) script to do this for $\ x=30, 300\ $ and $\ 3000\ $, for instance, and calculate the corresponding average change:

```
  for x in {30,300,3000} do
     oldp:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,x+25);
     newp:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,x+25);
     oldp[1,1]:=1;
     for i in [0..Round(x/25)-1] do
        for j in [i..25*i] do
           newp[1,j+2]:=newp[1,j+2]+oldp[1,j+1]/4;
           newp[1,j+6]:=newp[1,j+6]+oldp[1,j+1]/4;
           newp[1,j+11]:=newp[1,j+11]+oldp[1,j+1]/4;
           newp[1,j+26]:=newp[1,j+26]+oldp[1,j+1]/4;
        end for;
        oldp:=newp;
        newp:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,x+25);
      end for;
      for i in [Round(x/25)..x] do
         for j in [x..x+24] do
            newp[1,j+1]:=oldp[1,j+1];
         end for;
         for j in [i..x-1] do
            newp[1,j+2]:=newp[1,j+2]+oldp[1,j+1]/4;
            newp[1,j+6]:=newp[1,j+6]+oldp[1,j+1]/4;
            newp[1,j+11]:=newp[1,j+11]+oldp[1,j+1]/4;
            newp[1,j+26]:=newp[1,j+26]+oldp[1,j+1]/4;
         end for;
         oldp:=newp;
         newp:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,x+25);
      end for;
      av:=0;
      for i in [1..24] do
         av:=av+i*oldp[1,x+i+1];
      end for;
      print x, RealField(40)!av;
  end for;
```

If you copy this, paste it into the [online Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/), and run it (by pressing "submit"), it returns the  following values for the average change (rounded to $10$ decimal places):
\begin{align}
7.7501743224\ &\text{ for }\ x=30,\\
8.6589674863\ &\text{ for }\ x=300,\text{ and}\\
8.6585365854\ &\text{ for }\ x=3000\ .
\end{align}
The online Magma calculator doesn't provide enough resources to do the calculation for $\ x=3000000$. It would be possible to do it with the Magma package on a PC, if you had access to one, but this turns out to be unnecessary anyway.  It turns out that as $\ x\rightarrow\infty\ $ the distribution of change converges to one with rational entries:
\begin{array}{l|c|c|c|c|}
\text{Change}&0&1{-}4&5{-}9&10{-}24\\
\hline
\text{Probability}&\frac{4}{41}&\frac{3}{41}&\frac{2}{41}&\frac{1}{41}\\
\hline
\end{array}
Accordingly, the average change converges to
$$
\frac{3}{41} \cdot 10+\frac{2}{41} \cdot 35+\frac{1}{41} \cdot 255=\frac{355}{41}=8.\overline{65853}\ .
$$
I haven't bothered trying to prove that the distribution of change converges, although I  already thought it was likely to do so when I started looking at the problem.  I'm a little surprised, however, that the limit turned out to have rational entries.  Running the above script shows that for $\ x=3000\ $ the fraction $\ \frac{355}{41}\ $ already approximates the average change to more than $20$ decimal places.

If you try running the above script for $\ x=5000\ $, the online Magma calculator reaches its time limit before finishing the calculation.  If you change the arithmetic of the script from exact rational arithmetic to $50$ significant digit floating point, however, the output shows that for $\ x=5000\ $ the fraction $\ \frac{355}{41}\ $  approximates the average change correctly to $37$
decimal places.

Consequently, for $\ x=3000000\ $, the distribution of change will differ negligibly from  that in the table above, and the average change will differ negligibly from $\ \frac{355}{41}\ $.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I think the key is to assume that x−24 to x−1 are nearly equally probable at time τ−1. (τ is the smallest number of coins that total value is larger than x).